# Как сделать данный код более компактным?

Tags: python, инспекция-кода, рефакторинг

```
def rcvdata(cmd,size):
    global s;
    s.settimeout(1)
    try:
        sendCommand(cmd);data = s.recv(size)

    except:
        try:
           sendCommand(cmd);data = s.recv(size)

        except:
            try:
                sendCommand(cmd);data = s.recv(size)

            except:
                try:
                    sendCommand(cmd);data = s.recv(size)

                except:
                    try:
                        sendCommand(cmd);data = s.recv(size)

                    except:                       
                        try:
                            sendCommand(cmd);data = s.recv(size)

                        except:
                            s.close()

    return(data)
```

Comment: `while` на `N` раз?

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 5):

```
def rcvdata(cmd, size):
    data = None
    s.settimeout(1)
    for trying in range(6):
        try:
            sendCommand(cmd)
            data = s.recv(size)
        except:
            if trying == 5:  # Последняя попытка, неудачная
                s.close()
    return data
```

Или если надобности в каких-то действиях после цикла нет, то можно уменьшить вложенность:

```
def rcvdata(cmd, size):
    s.settimeout(1)
    for _ in range(6):
        try:
            sendCommand(cmd)
            return s.recv(size)
        except:
            pass  # Здесь по желанию можно воткнуть time.sleep(1)
    # Сюда мы попадаем только после шести неудачных попыток
    s.close()
    return None
```

Почитайте в любом учебнике Python про циклы.

---

А ещё нехорошо перехватывать ВСЕ исключения, потому что тогда программу невозможно будет закрыть (выход — тоже вполне себе исключения SystemExit и иногда KeyboardInterrupt), а также будут пропущены баги внутри `sendCommand`. Следует перехватывать только те исключения, которые здесь ожидаются (здесь, наверно, что-то вроде `socket.error` или `IOError`).

А ещё `s.recv(size)` не гарантирует, что придёт ровно `size` байт — в зависимости от качества связи, особенностей ОС, фазы Луны и звёзд на небе может вернуться меньше. А по таймауту — и вовсе просто ноль байт. Не знаю, нужно ли это в вашем конкретном случае, но про это желательно не забывать.

В общем, плоховат код всё равно

Comment: Не используйте `except:pass`, чтобы разрешить `KeyboardInterrupt`, `SystemExit` замените на `except Exception` и/или чтобы баги найти, например ведущим к `AttributeError`, можно  `logging.exception("error")` использовать. Текст у вас об этом говорит, но код использует `except:pass`

Comment: @jfs не смею менять логику вырванного из контекста кода. Если автор уточнит, что как ему надо — поменяю

Comment: Учитывая состояние кода в вопросе—"не смею менять логику" это отговорка. Мы с вами не на сайте помощи автору, ваш ответ должен помогать другим посетителям, а не в расчёте что у автора крайне редкий случай когда вредная во всех остальных случаях конструкция является оправданной.

Comment: Вот именно учитывая состояние в кода в вопросе, я и не смею менять логику. :) Другие посетители вполне прочитают моё примечание и ваш первый комментарий. К тому же вопрос совсем не про перехват исключений.

Comment: учитывая состояние кода вероятность багов в коде внутри `except:pass` близка к 100%—ещё важнее избегать подобного кода здесь.

Answer (score 1):

Предложу свой вариант с задержкой между вызовом `recv` в 1 секунду и 10 попытками:

```
def rcvdata(cmd, size):
    s.settimeout(1)
    
    max_count = 10
    
    while True:        
        try:
            max_count -= 1
            if max_count <= 0:
                return 

            sendCommand(cmd)
            data = s.recv(size)
            return data
    
        finally:
            s.close()
```

Comment: С учётом того, что мы не знаем, откуда код в вопросе и где он используется и что творится с `s` вне функции, такие додумывания могут оказаться не совсем верными

Comment: Кстати, здесь есть задержка в одну секунду даже после успешной попытки

Comment: согласен, просто показываю пример )
я не был уверен в задержке, спасибо за уточнение :)

Answer (score 0):

Оставлю и я свой вариант_)

```
def rcvdata(cmd,size):
    global s;
    s.settimeout(1)
    t = 0
    while t!=7:
        try:
            sendCommand(cmd)
            data = s.recv(size)
        except:
            t+=1
    s.close()
```